# iOS Application partitioning / MVC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, model-view-controller, ios

I've been playing around with iOS development and I'm getting to the stage where I want to create something beyond a simple app. However, I'm not confident that I understand how to partition an application correctly.

For the purposes of simplicity, imagine a (very) simple audio player application. Let's say there are two view controllers, accessible via a UITabBarController which is instantiated the main AppDelegate class.

Each of these view controllers has the following responsibility:

1. PlayerViewController - A sound player which plays the “current” audio sample when the user presses a button.
2. SelectorViewController - A sample selector, that uses a UIPickerView to display the available audio samples so that the user can select which sample they want to play.

So far, so good. However, what I don't quite understand is where I should store the data on the available samples, so that both of the views can find out information on the available samples, trigger a sample to play, etc.

As both view controllers need to access this “model level” information, would creating an “audio manager” singleton class be a sensible approach, or is there (much, much more likely I'm guessing) a better means of solving this problem that I'm overlooking.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used this pattern (Singleton data manager) several times in serious apps. It's quite straightforward, easy to understand, easy to use, although this pattern is despised by OOP purists.

If nobody tells you it's wrong to use a singleton, go ahead, just be sure to check Apple's documentation on the recommended implementation (there is a bunch of methods to overload).

Oh and BTW, Apple uses it a lot in the iOS SDK, so it's a common practice (see class methods beginning with 'shared').

UPDATE:

Another possibility is reusing an already existing singleton, the Application delegate for instance. It might feel cleaner, or not, it's more a matter of taste. It has the advantage of giving a clear "entry point" where you allocate/create/init your data manager.

Comment: It just feels a bit odd that this is the only way to enable multiple controllers to access the same data. Create a singleton for all models that need to be accessed by multiple controllers just feels wrong, at least at the moment.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice something. Why do you need to access the whole data store in the player view? It only needs to have its currently playing file, doesn't it?

Comment: In this specific, perhaps ill choosen, example I wouldn't. That said, it's the general heuristic I'm after.

Comment: A noob question, but if I use the app delegate approach, how can I call a method in that class from within one of the view controllers?

Comment: You have the singleton: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`, that you need to cast into your specific AppDelegate type. Then you can access the properties you'd add in your AppDelegate.

Comment: @jv42 - I highly advise against using the UIApplicationDelegate for that. It's purpose it to assist for application wide events like starting, stopping and state transitioning. Putting all kinds of shared data in it makes for less reusable code.

Comment: @Rengers So, you think a standalone singleton would be the appropriate choice, or ?

Comment: @Rengers: as stated above, I'd go for the manager singleton, that's what I've done in the past and surely will in the future.

Comment: Yes, I think a standalone singleton would be much better then abusing the App Delegate for this. Good choice :)

Comment: Could downvoter explain his downvote? That would be much more useful.

Answer (score 0):

If the source of your data is in a remote server and it comes to your app as an XML file, you can also get it whenever you want with a kind of source downloader class.

That way you don't have to care about keeping things in memory when they are not necessary. Just get it from the remote source, parse it and then release it.

Another way of achieving this more careful use of memory is to get your data from a sqlite database using Core Data. But some people thinks it is too much complicated for a simple app and prefer running queries by hand.

Comment: All of these things are true. Completely un-related to the question, but true. :-)

Comment: well, I just thought it wasn't necessary to go deeper in the design details and thought pointing out ways to solve the problem was good enough.